# Blogger section doesn't appear on the layout page

Tags: xml, blogger

There is a problem about the layout page that is in Blogger Dashboard. I can see main and sidebar section on the layout page, but page-sidebar does not appear. Why is it happening?

```xml
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType in {&quot;static_page&quot;}'>
    <div class='col-sm-3 page-sidebar-area'>
          <b:section id='page-sidebar'/>
    </div>
</b:if>

<div class="col-sm-9">
    <b:section id="main">..</b:section>
</div>

<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType in {&quot;index&quot;,&quot;item&quot;}'></b:if>
    <div class='col-sm-3 sidebar-area'>
        <b:section id='sidebar'>..</b:section>
    </div>
</b:if>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out problem. I defined to conditional statement into section tag, like this:

```xml
<b:section cond='data:blog.pageType in {&quot;static_page&quot;}' id='page-sidebar'/>
```

Currently, the section appears on the layout page and works properly.